# Как узнать путь файла с помощью имени файла?

Tags: c++, файлы, файловая-система

Вот водиться имя файла в программу с помощью аргумента. Можно ли как-то узнать его путь полный путь? Реализация с помощью библиотеки **Windows.h**

Answer (score 1):

Собственно, а зачем `<windows.h>`, если можно использовать стандартную библиотеку С++?

Функция [`absolute()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/absolute) из `<filesystems>`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
 
int main()
{
    std::filesystem::path p = "foo.c";
    std::cout << "Current path is " << std::filesystem::current_path() << '\n';
    std::cout << "Absolute path for " << p << " is " << fs::absolute(p) << '\n';
}
```

Но если очень хочется непереносимости — то без проблем, [GetFullPathName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfullpathnamea) к вашим услугам.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
 
int main()
{
    char fullpath[300];
    GetFullPathName("foo.c",300,fullpath,0);
    std::cout << "Absolute path is " << fullpath << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но к сожалению мне нужно реализовать это через **<windows.h>**

Comment: См. дополненный ответ...

Comment: Ага, но как я понял, может искать путь файла в папке проекта?

Comment: Что-то у вас какая-то не та задача... Вы выясняете, не как забить гвоздь, а какой рукой держать при этом микроскоп. Что вы хотите изначально?

Comment: Если объяснить проще, мне хотелось узнавать полный путь до файла или папки, имя которого я ввожу в консоль с помощью аргумента. И самое главное, файл/папка может располагаться на диске где угодно

Comment: Тогда зачем вам искать что-то в папке проекта, если вы решаете задачу гораздо более общую?

Comment: Пытаюсь сам додумать алгоритм) Но....видно,  вообще не туда копаю. Если сможете, не подскажите, а то уже несколько часов сижу над данной задачей